# Heroku - task ran by Schedular (CRON)

Tags: heroku, cron, request

I need every night to run a task by Schedular (CRON). This task can take about 10 minutes (sometimes less, sometimes more).

On Heroku is set up the limit for every task/request only 30s. So my question is - will be my task finished correctly or will be cancelled after 30 seconds (because "usual" request is finished, only after 30s is displayed error into the browser, but I am not sure, how it is in the case of CRON)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job should complete because you're not using an HTTP request as proxy to initiate the task.

Consider using a background job on a worker for this. Your periodic process would then just have to start the worker and it wouldn't matter how long the process took.

Comment: But another worker cost $35 and this is just a sample-app... however, when will be run this task, so then if some visitor come to the app (in the time when the task is ran), so he would have to wait until the  task will be finished? Am I right?

Comment: That all depends on the task itself. If it's something that changes state on a user variable, for instance, then they either see pre- or post-change. If, on the other hand, it's something more global and critical then you should schedule it to occur with the minimum disruption to your users. Worst case scenario you display some kind of 'Pending...' message that explains why the particular feature is unavailable and a rough estimate as to when it will be back. You could set a flag in a file or the database to signal that the process is running.